# Android margins not working when the view was added dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

I am adding some View to the LinearLayout dynamically:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100);
view.setLayoutParams(params);
parent.addView(view);
```

However, the margins are not getting applied. The following:

```
view.invalidate();
view.requestLayout();
parent.invalidate();
parent.requestLayout();
```

didn't work. However, if I force the activity to recreate (e.g. turn off and on my mobile phone), the margins get applied. Calling *activity.recreate()* also works, but it's too slow.

How to force layout to recalculate margins? Probably, there's something wrong in the flow? I tried to add my views to the root after creation, add children before and after applying properties, but this didn't work for me.

**UPD:**
I tried to repeat the bug programmatically and got it with this code:

```
LinearLayout base = new LinearLayout(context);
LayoutParams params1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
base.setLayoutParams(params1);    
base.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
root.addView(base);

LinearLayout another1 = new LinearLayout(context);
LayoutParams params2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
another1.setLayoutParams(params2);
another1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
another1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
base.addView(another1);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(context);
tv1.setText("SOME TEST TEXT 1");
tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
LayoutParams params4 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params4.setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100);
tv1.setLayoutParams(params4);
another1.addView(tv1);

TextView tv2 = new TextView(context);
tv2.setText("SOME TEST TEXT 2");
tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
LayoutParams params5 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params4.setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100);
tv2.setLayoutParams(params5);
another1.addView(tv2);
```

[image: Here's what I got]

I expect margins to be applied, but they are not. What is the correct order of initializing such a view?

Comment: AFAIK, that will not compile. All forms of `addView()` take the `View` as a parameter, and `parent.addView(params)` does not seem to pass in a `View`.

Comment: set margin after adding view to parent view.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, changed addView parameter.
I tried to set params after adding to parent view, got the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my trouble was in DP to PX converter that just wasn't initialized at that moment. However, to clarify everything, my example above is just an error (I didn't change params4 to params5 when adding the second TextView. 
Also while testing everything, I found out that the order of adding layouts and their parameters doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

You probably added child views to the parent view in onCreate().

In onCreate(), parent view does not have actual size.

If you have to do it in onCreate(), try following code.

```
    final ViewTreeObserver observer = parent.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100);
            TextView view = new TextView(context);
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
            parent.addView(view);
            observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    };
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      layoutParams.setMargins(30,20,30,0);
```

Hope this will help!